# Swift: Change position of elements on storyboard through code

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, uikit

Probably a very trivial Swift question.

I've got a view on my storyboard with various `UIelements` (labels, images etc). 
What I want to do is change the position of some of these elements through code (so not using the storyboard or autolayout features).

When I create my elements dynamically I can just type:

```
distanceLabel.frame = CGRectMake( 100, 200, 50, 50); // set new position exactly
```

or

```
distanceLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(0,0)
```

However this doesn't work for elements on my storboard (I'm calling them through the IBOutlets I've created). Any simple trick / tip / hint to do this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Has Interface Builder automatically created layout constraints for your UI elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use outlets to modify constraints. Set `constant` property by code to modify the layout.

[image: Outlet to NSLayoutConstraint]